# Using properties in Protocols and @synthesize as a shortcut to protocol implementation

Tags: objective-c

Say I create a class and a protocol like this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@required
- (void) doSomething;
@end

@interface MyClass id<MyProtocol>
@property int aNumber;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize aNumber = aNumber_;
- (void) doSomething { aNumber_++; }
@end
```

I can obviously pass instances of MyClass around by treating them as `id<MyProtocol>`s. I can't access `aNumber` though, if I'm dealing with something declared as `id<MyProtocol>`. That's expected.

I needed to do this recently. I wanted to keep using the protocol to refer to instances of my class (runtime determined) but I also wanted to access the classes properties too. I found that I could do this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@required
- (void) doSomething;
- (int) aNumber;
@end
```

And now anywhere I have an instance of an `id<MyProtocol>` I can also call `[instance aNumber]`, *without* having to code up accessors directly - the `synthesise` call effectively implements that part of protocol for me. I could also add the setter as well, if I like.

Have I stumbled upon an intentional feature, or is this sort of thing a Bad Idea which will end up causing me problems down the line?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely intentional.

When you write:

```
@property int aNumber;
```

this is really just shorthand for:

```
- (int) aNumber;
- (void) setaNumber:(int)value;
```

and the dot notation, `object.property`, is just shorthand for calling one of these two methods (depending on whether you are reading from, or assigning to, the property).

The `@synthesize` statement just writes the two methods for you.

Comment: Thanks, as long as its not going to surprise other programmers later on then it's a useful trick.

Comment: You can if you wish put `@property (readonly) int aNumber;` in your protocol - which is of course another way of writing `- (int) aNumber;`

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with properties; I was more asking if the usage with protocols was idiomatic. Seems like it is.